# How to make Promise get rid of long chain?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I want to separate my code logic. And the long chain is somewhat difficult to be controlled by condition.

I wrote a test code:

```
var Q, f, p;

Q = require('q');

f = function(t, info) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(info);
    return deferred.resolve();
  }, t);
  return deferred.promise;
};

p = f(500, 0);

p.then(function() {
  return f(300, 1);
});

p.then(function() {
  return f(100, 2);
});
```

I hope the result to be:

```
0
1
2
```

But I always get:

```
0
2
1
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to chain the promises:

```
p = f(500, 0);

p = p.then(function() {
  return f(300, 1);
});

p = p.then(function() {
  return f(100, 2);
});
```

Or more idiomatic:

```
f(500, 0).then(function() {
  return f(300, 1);
}).then(function() {
  return f(100, 2);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You must chain the `then` so that `then` is called on the returned promise :

```
p = f(500, 0);
p.then(function() {
  return f(300, 1);
}).then(function() {
  return f(100, 2);
});
```

There's no problem in passing a promise, that's what you already do (`f` returns a promise).

Comment: What if I want to separate my code logic. Or I may get a long chain. Is there any good solution?

Comment: The promise you return from `p.then(...)` can be passed as argument and chained from some other point. You may also nest them. I frequently do this kind of thing. And of course there's no problem in having a long chain.